# Letters to Array Matlab

Tags: matlab

Good Day!
How can I make an array of letters if I input for example `a=[letters]` and my wanted out put is `b= [ l e t t e r s]` ? I want to use each character in some functions. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Leonid Beschastny is right, array of letters, or string, can be accessed just like any other array in Matlab, `b(1)` will contain `l`.  Is this what you are looking for?  Also, you may want to include the single quote on your examples; `a = ['letters']`

Comment: I would like to loop in to each letters, I will compare each letter to corresponding matches. That is why I want to make a array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can just loop over a string in the normal fashion:

```
b = 'test'; for t = 1:length(b); fprintf('%dth one is %s\n',t,b(t)); end
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I found out the culprit why 'length(letters)' keeps returning 1. Because in my function `enterword(letters)' matlab don't consider letters as a string. Well I want may function to be string input function but I can't find way how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

String is an array of letters, so

```
b = 'test'
```

is the same thing as

```
b = ['t', 'e', 's', 't']
```

Strings in MatLab are fully functional arrays. Use them freely.

Comment: thanks for fast response. My function is somewhat like enterword(Test) then I want to loop in the word Test in order to compare each letter to other word.